# Why do my PHP files show as text in browsers?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, php5

Long story short, my PHP files show as text in browsers rather than running the PHP script. I am aware that there are questions similar to this but none answer my question. I'm lost.

I have an Apache web server with a Linux OS (Debian). I have installed
apache2, php5, libapache2-mod-php5 and php5-common. After every configuration change I've made, I have restarted the Apache web server and there is no difference.

I'm not too sure which configuration files I need to show for you guys to help answer my question. I will edit this question to include the relevant information.

To clarify, my question is: Why do my PHP files show as text in browsers?

P.S. Everything used to work until I completely removed Apache and reinstalled it. Now it's broken.

Comment: Someone could likely ask for your PHP.ini file. Is there any source you can show us?

Comment: Or may be you did mod-php is not loaded

Comment: Was gonna say, check apache config file for the PHP extension.

Comment: The `php.ini` file is large in terms of length and content. Are there any specific sections that are relevant?

Answer (score 1):

as the root user:

```
/usr/sbin/a2enmod php5
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: When running `/usr/sbin/a2enmod php5`, I get the error, `ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!`. I have already run `apt-get install php5` though?

Comment: You need php5 and also libapache2-mod-php5, run apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Comment: When I run, `apt-get install php5` and `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` I get in return, `php5 is already the newest version.` and `libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version.` respectively.

Comment: please be sure that the /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf file exists, and paste its content

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a solution online at http://digitizor.com/2012/09/03/how-to-fix-module-php5-does-not-exist-error-in-apache-linux/ Thank you :)